# In IntelliJ what's the shortcut to call a function with the expression before the cursor as parameter

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Let's just say I am typing `foo.getBar()` and now I would like to call my method `stuff()` on that result, to produce `stuff(foo.getBar())`. If I have to do it manually, I have to surround my expression with parentheses and move the cursor before the first parenthesis, then write my method. Is there any shortcut that would do it for me?

It means go from

```
foo.getBar()|
```

to

```
|(foo.getBar());
```

in one shortcut, with '|' being my cursor.

Comment: You may create postfix completion template (e.g. "$END$($EXPR$)"): https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2019/09/11/increase-productivity-with-custom-postfix-completion-templates/

Comment: I looked into the postfix completion templates that already existed and I noticed the one I was looking for already existed, it's `arg` template, so no need to create my own one. I'll create an answer with this, thanks for making me look into the right place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type `.arg` after your expression and it will wrap the expression into an argument with the cursor before.

You have to enable Postfix Completion (which is enabled by default I think). You can find it in Editor > General > Postfix Completion